# Drivers Editor : Adding more than 2 keyframes

Tags: rigging, drivers, properties, custom-properties

I'm trying to adapt some Maya rig for Blender, and I'm *translating Maya's Set Driven Key to Drivers*. But for the life of me, I can't seem to figure out how to add more than two keyframes to my driver's curve

[image: I'd want to add a third keyframe at 2.0 with a custom value]

I want to add a third keyframe to my cursor emplacement (2.0) to map it to a custom value (different than the values of 1.0 and 0.0)
The project is essentially **mapping the value of my driver (custom value) to specific X values** (coordinate), **non-linearly**. *For example 1.0 = 1.21, 2.0 = 2.35, 3.0 = 4.88 etc.*

In Maya the setup was quite easy, just setting up keyframes to specific values in the graph Editor but Blender doesn't seems to allow it for some reasons.

Any clues as to why/How to work around it is necessary?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the driver curve editor, use Ctrl Right click to add a keyframe, or shift D to duplicate an existing one.

Then on the N side panel you can enter exact values for the selected keyframe, choosing curve type and handles behaviour.

[image]